# Speed up Laravel with Open Swoole

Tags: php, laravel, http, swoole, openswoole

I have install laravel-open-swool package to serv my laravel project in swool of nginx or apache .

```
composer require swooletw/laravel-swoole
```

Now when i want to start http server the error happen

```
Call to undefined function SwooleTW\Http\Commands\swoole_version()
```

I installed the latest version of open swool with this commands in ubuntu 20 and php8.1

```
apt update
apt install -y software-properties-common && add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php -y
apt install -y software-properties-common && add-apt-repository ppa:openswoole/ppa -y
apt install -y php8.1-openswoole
```

I want to serv my laravel project with Open Swool package